# Compare Database Prices and Choose the lowest price

Tags: database, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code which is coded in WordPress:

```
<?php
      global $product;
      global $wpdb;
      $locations = get_the_terms( $product->ID, 'pa_location');
      foreach ( $locations as $locationz ) {
        $location = $locationz->name;
      }
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM rates WHERE location = '" . $location . "';";
      $query = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
      foreach ( $query as $price ) { 
           $regularprice = $price->fareprice;
      }
?>
```

Now, the problem I have is choosing the lowest price using the location column where there are 4 SAME LOCATIONS.

I know I can use `min();` but how do I store `$regularprices` on an array and use the `min();` to chose the lowest price?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it already 
'<?php
   foreach ( $query as $price ) {
    $prices[] = $price;
    }
    $regularprice = min($prices);
?>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store `$regularprices` on an array, you can use `$regularprices[]` and then use `min()` function, like this:

```
foreach ( $query as $price ) 
{ 
    $regularprice[] = $price->fareprice;
}
$lowestPrice = min($regularprice);
```

I also notice that your variable `$location` only has 1 value after `foreach` function, if you want to get prices from all locations by product id, you should change your code to this:

```
foreach ( $locations as $locationz ) 
 {
     $location[] = $locationz->name;
 }
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rates WHERE location IN '" . $location . "';";
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks but I already solved it an hour before you posted, but anyways, this is the correct answer :)